# Unique Id for my android app

Tags: android, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I want to create a unique ID for my android app so that my server can identify from which device the request has come and send messages to the app accordingly. I read that ANDROID_ID is not safe to use as a unique identifier as it can be compromised on a rooted device. And also some manufacturer don't even provide it.

Is UUID safe to use for my porpose ? Is it really the globally unique id for the app ? If yes, I am planning to store it using the keystore so that I can keep it until the app uninstalls. Is it the right approach. Please suggest.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html "I am planning to store it using the keystore so that I can keep it until the app uninstalls" -- I would hope that an app's keystore entries are removed whenever the app's internal storage is cleared, so I am not certain that this will be a benefit for you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html Unique IDs also have privacy issues involved, so please read this document completely

Comment: I want to keep this id as long as my app is installed. On Uninstall its ok to reset it. Thanks for the nice article on ids. They talk about using Instance ID or UUID for my purpose. Is it ok to use any of them ? Any known advantages / disadvantages of the other ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually safe to use UUID, this is a helper function I created to get the UUID myself,keep it in Helper.java , so you will call it :

```
Helper.getDeviceId(context);
```

also don forget the change String sharedPrefDbName variable to your sharef db name, also you can store the UUID in DB or local file incase app is uninstalled like you said.

```
//uuid
static  String deviceId;

static String sharedPrefDbName = "MyAPPDB";

/**
 * getDeviceId
 * @param context
 * @return String
 */
public static String getDeviceId(Context context){

    //lets get device Id if not available, we create and save it
    //means device Id is created once

   //if the deviceId is not null, return it
    if(deviceId != null){
        return deviceId;
    }//end

    //shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefDbName,context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //lets get the device Id
    deviceId = sharedPref.getString("device_id",null);

    //if the saved device Id is null, lets create it and save it

    if(deviceId == null) {

        //generate new device id
        deviceId = generateUniqueID();

        //Shared Preference editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor = sharedPref.edit();

        //save the device id
        sharedPrefEditor.putString("device_id",deviceId);

        //commit it
        sharedPrefEditor.commit();
    }//end if device id was null

    //return
    return deviceId;
}//end get device Id


/**
 * generateUniqueID - Generate Device Id
 * @return
 */
public static String generateUniqueID() {

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    return id;
}//end method
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was reading about the different kinds of ids that we can use. For my purpose Instance ID or UUID is useful. But which one is better, if it is the case ?

Comment: After some research I ended up choosing UUID.. This is quote from android dev (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#version_specific_details_identifiers_in_m) : "#3: Use an Instance ID or a privately stored GUID whenever possible for all other use-cases except payment fraud prevention and telephony. For the vast majority of non-ads use-cases, an instance ID or GUID should be sufficient. " , so in my case the UUID was perfect since I needed to track user presence and device changes, I sync the local UUID to my remote server , so every x seconds the app confirm if..

Comment: ..they match, if they dont , a new sms auth is required to authenticate the user on the new device ,and a new UUID is regenerated and resynced to my server.. This helps prevents multiple devices using the same account ,I got my inspiration from whatsapp ..

Comment: If user clears their SharedPref, then `device_id` is lost